# How to not offer a task to specific worker on Twilio

Tags: twilio, twilio-php, twilio-click-to-call, twilio-api

I am new in Twilio and i have been facing an issue while designing outbound dialer currently preview dialing. If a worker rejects a task than the same task should not be offered to that worker again. 
How do i handle this case?

Answer (score 4):

Typically if a worker rejects the task, the worker should be moved to an unavailable activity. Otherwise, if the worker is the only available and qualified worker, TaskRouter will continue to create new reservations.

You can specify a new activitySid upon rejection, so that the worker is moved to an unavailable activity at the same time:

https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/taskrouter/worker-js#reservation-reject

Here, making the worker activity unavailable would simply mean the worker will not be able to get any task.

But let's look at a more complicated use case where a Worker can accept, reject or cancel tasks. They need to be available to make this choice.

If you have only that agent, and they are available, then there is no way to prevent that agent from receiving the Task, unless you manipulate the Task attributes or worker attributes so that TaskRouter doesn’t assign the Task. For example, you could update TaskAttributes to have a rejected worker SID list, and then in the workflow say that worker.sid NOT IN task.rejectedWorkerSids.

And the ability to do this Target Workers Expression just shipped as a bug fix today! It should look like:

```
worker.sid NOT IN task.rejectedWorkers
```

Comment: @Megan-Speir - can you provide a link to the above use in the docs?  I'm trying to do the opposite - i.e. tag a task with a target_worker_sid and then have the workflow deliver the task to the appropriate worker (from within the same queue).  Should this be possible with something like worker.sid == task.target_worker_sid ?  I can't make it work and hope I'm not trying something impossible.  (I do have the attribute set on the task.)

Comment: Hi @James, Can you create a new question with a more detailed snippet of the code you're using?

Comment: Thanks @MeganSpeir this is great!

Comment: Has this functionality been broken again? My `Worker Target Expression` is set to the above, yet the call refuses to assign. Initially there is no value for `rejectedWorkers` on the task, does this need to be set when creating the task first time around?

Comment: I think I've now resolved this. The issue came that `rejectedWorkers` was set as `null` in my task data. The expression parser then saw this as being a scalar value, and caused my `NOT IN` expression to error.