# Twilio Taskrouter: How to prevent last worker in queue from being reassigned rejected task?

Tags: node.js, twilio, twilio-taskrouter

I'm using NodeJS to manage a Twilio Taskrouter workflow.  My goal is to have a task assigned to an Idle worker in the main queue identified with `queueSid`, unless one of the following is true:

1. No workers in the queue are set to Idle
2. Reservations for the task have already been rejected by every worker in the queue

In these cases, the task should fall through to the next queue identified with `automaticQueueSid`.  Here is how I construct the JSON for the workflow (it includes a filter such that an inbound call from an agent should not generate an outbound call to that same agent):

```
configurationJSON(){
    var config={
        "task_routing":{
            "filters":[
                {

                    "filter_friendly_name":"don't call self",
                    "expression":"1==1",
                    "targets":[
                        {
                            "queue":queueSid,
                            "expression":"(task.caller!=worker.contact_uri) and (worker.sid NOT IN task.rejectedWorkers)",
                            "skip_if": "workers.available == 0"
                        },
                        {
                            "queue":automaticQueueSid
                        }
                    ]

                }
            ],
            "default_filter":{
                "queue":queueSid
            }
        }
    }
    return config;
}
```

This results in no reservation being created after the task reaches the queue.  My event logger shows that the following events have occurred:

```
workflow.target-matched
workflow.entered
task.created
```

That's as far as it gets and just hangs there.  When I replace the line

```
"expression":"(task.caller!=worker.contact_uri) and (worker.sid NOT IN task.rejectedWorkers)"
```

with

```
"expression":"(task.caller!=worker.contact_uri)
```

Then the reservation is correctly created for the next available worker, or sent to `automaticQueueSid` if no workers are available when the call comes in, so I guess the `skip_if` is working correctly.  So maybe there is something wrong with how I wrote the target expression?

I tried working around this by setting a worker to unavailable once they reject a reservation, as follows:

```
clientWorkspace
.workers(parameters.workerSid)
.reservations(parameters.reservationSid)
.update({
    reservationStatus:'rejected'
})
.then(reservation=>{
//this function sets the worker's Activity to Offline
    var updateResult=worker.updateWorkerFromSid(parameters.workerSid,process.env.TWILIO_OFFLINE_SID);
})
.catch(err=>console.log("/agent_rejects: error rejecting reservation: "+err));
```

But what seems to be happening is that as soon as the reservation is rejected, before `worker.updateWorkerFromSid()` is called, Taskrouter has already generated a new reservation and assigned it to that same worker, and my Activity update fails with the following error:

```
Error: Worker [workerSid] cannot have its activity updated while it has 1 pending reservations.
```

Eventually, it seems that the worker is naturally set to Offline and the task does time out and get moved into the next queue, as shown by the following events/descriptions:

```
worker.activity.update
Worker [friendly name] updated to Offline Activity
reservation.timeout
Reservation [sid] timed out
task-queue.moved
Task [sid] moved out of TaskQueue [friendly name]
task-queue.timeout
Task [sid] timed out of TaskQueue [friendly name]
```

After this point the task is moved into the next queue `automaticQueueSid` to be handled by available workers registered with that queue.  I'm not sure why a timeout is being used, as I haven't included one in my workflow configuration.

I'm stumped--how can I get the task to successfully move to the next queue upon the last worker's reservation rejection?

UPDATE: although @philnash's answer helped me correctly handle the `worker.sid NOT IN task.rejectedWorkers` issue, I ultimately ended up implementing this feature using the RejectPendingReservations parameter when updating the worker's availability.

Comment: Are you adding the worker's SID to the task's `rejectedWorkers` attribute anywhere at all?

Comment: @philnash no, I assumed based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38799016/619177) that it was updated as part of Taskrouter's internal operations.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

`rejectedWorkers` is not an attribute that is automatically handled by TaskRouter. You reference [this answer by my colleague Megan](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38356604/how-to-not-offer-a-task-to-specific-worker-on-twilio/38799016#38799016) in which she says:

> For example, *you could update TaskAttributes to have a rejected worker SID list*, and then in the workflow say that worker.sid NOT IN task.rejectedWorkerSids.

So, in order to filter by a `rejectedWorkers` attribute you need to maintain one yourself, by [updating the task](https://www.twilio.com/docs/taskrouter/api/tasks#action-update) before you reject the reservation.

Let me know if that helps at all.

Comment: ok, I think I understand--Megan's answer was about Target Workers Expression in general shipping as a new feature, not specifically a built-in `rejectedWorkers` attribute in TaskAttributes.  I'll add this on my own and see if I can get it to work.

Comment: Right, you've got it there. There are no built in Task attributes, you have to add your own as they happen.

Comment: quick question: to update the Task attributes with the workerSid of the rejecting worker, it seems like I have to make two calls to `workspace.tasks(taskSid)`: one to fetch the Task's TaskAttributes, then I copy a local version of the TaskAttributes object, then update it with the added workerSid, then the second call to `workspace.tasks(taskSid).update()` to assign the updated TaskAttributes object back to the Task.  Is there a way to accomplish the same result with a single call to `workspace.tasks(taskSid).update()` instead?

Comment: In the [task assignment callback you should receive the tasks attributes](https://www.twilio.com/docs/taskrouter/handle-assignment-callbacks#assignment-callback-parameters), you could store them and then update with the extra rejected worker sid when your worker rejects the task.

Comment: Hi Phil, I had a question on this, if multiple workers are assigned in one step, is there a potential issue with updating the array rejectedWorkers if multiple workers reject the assignment simultaneously. Does this proposed solution have an issue under this scenario?

Comment: Tasks are only ever assigned to one worker at a time.

Answer (score 0):

I manage to do something similar using the assignment callback URL for the workflow that handles the routing of the task.

I created a serverless function that updates a task attribute like "rejected" to true and set that function URL as the callback mentioned.

Also, I add that attribute to the task creation and use it as a filter in the workflow matching step filters.

The difference here is what I needed was that if the call was rejected for any worker (at least once), it goes to another queue (with other business logic).

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Hi, it's better to provide a working example, to use as a guide to troubleshooting the problem