# Twilio Taskrouter: how to implement a "do not contact" list of WorkerSids in Workflow Configuration?

Tags: node.js, twilio, twilio-taskrouter

This question is similar to [this one I previously asked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55381603/twilio-taskrouter-how-to-prevent-last-worker-in-queue-from-being-reassigned-rej), in that I want the task to perform a Target Worker Expression check on a list of WorkerSids that I've added as one of the task's attributes.  But I think this problem is different enough to warrant its own question.

My goal is to associate a "do not contact" list of WorkerSids with a Task; these are workers who should not be assigned the task (maybe the customer previously had a bad interaction with them).

I have the following workflow configuration:

```
{
        "task_routing":{
            "filters":[
                {

                    "filter_friendly_name":"don't call self",
                    "expression":"1==1",
                    "targets":[
                        {
                            "queue":queueSid,
                            "expression":"(task.caller!=worker.contact_uri) and (worker.sid not in task.do_not_contact)",
                            "skip_if": "workers.available == 0"
                        },
                        {
                            "queue":automaticQueueSid
                        }
                    ]

                }
            ],
            "default_filter":{
                "queue":queueSid
            }
        }
    }
```

When I create a task, checking the Twilio Console, I can see that the task has the following attributes:

```
{"from_country":"US","do_not_contact":["WORKER_SID1_HERE","WORKER_SID_2_HERE"],

... bunch of other attributes...
}
```

So I know that the task has successfully been assigned the array of WorkerSids as one of its attributes.

There is only one worker who is Idle and whose attributes match the `queueSid` TaskQueue.  That worker's SID is `WORKER_SID1_HERE`, so the only available worker is ineligible to receive the task reservation.  So what should happen is that the first target expression `worker.sid not in task.do_not_contact` returns `false`, and the task falls through to the `automaticQueueSid` TaskQueue.

Instead, the task remains in `queueSid` unassigned.  The following sequence of Taskrouter events are logged:

```
task-queue.entered
Task TASK_SID entered TaskQueue QUEUESID_QUEUENAME

task.created
Task TASK_SID created

workflow.target-matched
Task TASK_SID matched a workflow target

workflow.entered
Task TASK_SID entered Workflow WORKFLOW_NAME
```

What do I need to change to get the desired workflow behavior?

Answer (score 0):

Changing the `skip_if` to

```
"skip_if": "1==1"
```

solved the problem.

Per Twilio developer support, the `worker.sid not in task.do_not_contact` returns true for workers who are unavailable but are also not in `do_not_contact`, so the target expression still returns a set of workers, and then the `"skip_if": "workers.available==0"` returns false because technically there is one "available" worker--the one who is ineligible due to the `do_not_contact` list.

What's needed is for the `skip_if` to always return true, so when the first target processes the task without assigning it, the `skip_if` then passes it to the next target, as discussed in [Taskrouter Workflow documentation](https://www.twilio.com/docs/taskrouter/worker-presence):

"TaskRouter will only skip a routing step in a Workflow if:

- No Reservations are immediately created when a Task enters the routing step
- The Skip Timeout expression evaluates to true"